# Connection refused when Host OS(Ubuntu) telnet the Guest OS(Windows XP) of the Virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking, telnet

I can't telnet the Guest OS(Windows xp) in my ubuntu machine but I can successfully ping its IP address.

In the network settings of guest os, I enabled two adapters. Here are the  the settings of the two adapters.

For the first adapter:

```
Attached to: NAT 
Adapter: Intel PRO/1000 MT Server(82545SEM)
Promiscuous Mode: Deny 
Cable Connect: enabled
```

For the second adapter:

```
Attached to: Host-only Adapter
Name: vboxnet0 
Adapter: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop(82545SEM)
Promiscuous Mode: Deny 
Cable Connect: enabled
```

I added port **1234** in the Exceptions of Windows Firewall Settings in guest OS just for testing. I can ping the IP Address and ssh the Host OS.

This is the result when I executed the telnet command.

```
user@micmic:~$ telnet 192.168.56.101 1234
Trying 192.168.56.101...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
sudo apt-get install telnetd-ssl
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```